# Java get upcoming date from day input

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have the following input

```
    String day = "Tuesday";
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E");
    Date date1 = dayFormat.parse(day);
```

And today date is 2012-10-19. By entering the day, I want to get back the next upcoming date and time.
How do I convert the Tuesday to string as following: 2012-10-20 00:00?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to get the next Monday using the `Calendar` class.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();  
int weekday = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  
if (weekday != Calendar.MONDAY)  
{  
    // calculate how much to add  
    // the 2 is the difference between Saturday and Monday  
    int days = (Calendar.SATURDAY - weekday + 2) % 7;  
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);  
}  
// now is the date you want  
Date date = now.getTime();  
String format = new SimpleDateFormat(...).format(date);
```

From: http://www.coderanch.com/t/385117/java/java/date-next-Monday

More: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/GetNextMonday.htm

Comment: Nice googling - anything you want to add yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for simple date manipulation. For example:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //gets a localized Calendar instance
calendar.setTime(date1);                    //sets the Calendar time to your date
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);             //adds 1 day
Date date2 = calendar.getTime();            //gets the resulting date
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Calendar` API as follows -

```
    String day = "Tue";
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");

    Date date1 = dayFormat.parse(day);        
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1); 

    //just keep adding a day to current date until the day of week is same
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
    while(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Output:

> Tue Oct 23 22:34:25 CDT 2012